# Sprite Kit Realistic Bone Animation

Tags: ios, animation, sprite, physics, sprite-kit

I'm developing a game with Sprite Kit. I'm new to the framework and I'm new to the iOS game developement. What happens is, I have physics enabled in my project, so, let's say, I have a sprite and something hits it and it falls. That's ok, that's what I wanted, of course, but, I wanted to make a reallistic falling animation. I created several texture atlas and that's how I tried to create a realistic animation, but it's not that great. Isn't there any way to make it more realistic? Like moving it like a real skeleton, the head, arms and legs move independently from the torso, do I have to create several sprites and like join them? I really have no idea, please help me and thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do I have to create several sprites and like join them?

More specifically, you'd create several physics bodies and join them together. And yes, each one would of course have a sprite associated with it. There are several ways to join physics bodies -- hinges, springs, rigid joints, etc. You can read more about it in [*Connecting Physics Bodies*](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW5) in the *Sprite Kit Programming Guide*.

Comment: Thank you! Are there any good tutorials that you know of? I searched the web and could not find anything useful, also, Apple's documentation is not very helpful in this situation.